# Android table creation Failure (while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: sqlite

While compiling:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SeasonMasterDB` 
  (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
   `id` TEXT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `name` TEXT
  );
```

that is why you are getting an error. Please help me, this is my code:

```
@Table(name = "SeasonMasterDB",database = AppDatabase.class)`enter code here`
    public class SeasonMasterDB extends Model {
    @PrimaryKey
    public Long id;
    @Column(name = "id")
    public String idValue;

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String name;

    public SeasonMasterDB()
    {
    }

    public SeasonMasterDB(String name,String id)
    {
        this.idValue = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two columns with the same name. Rename one of your `id` columns.